# is there putAll like method for dict in python?

Tags: python

Is there a method like putAll() for dict in python? I did not find a method in the document that seems to do this. Sure I can iterate over the key set and put every thing in the new dict, but I think there might be a better way.

Also (this might be another question), is 'Python Library Reference' considered the API document for python? I'm more used to javadoc like API document that has a list of classes and methods. With 'Python Library Reference', I always wonder if all methods of a class are listed and there's no link that I can jump around to see the definition of parameters and return type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are talking about Java's `putAll` for maps, [`dict.update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) would be the equivalent in Python:

```
>>> d1 = { 1: 2, 3: 4 }
>>> d2 = { 5: 6, 3: 1 }
>>> d1.update(d2)
>>> d1
{1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 6}
```

Regarding the documentation, there is an [overview](http://docs.python.org/library/) which links all the specific module documentation. In your specific instance, you'd then click on [Mapping Types — dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and browser through the available operations.

Comment: Great, thanks. I missed update(). Just didn't realize it might be the one I needed.

Comment: @DenMark: Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem (which it seems to).

Answer (score 1):

Apropos the documentation, the library reference is the go to place for the documentation. The [global module index](http://docs.python.org/modindex.html) is another place that lists all the modules so that you can quickly find something.

The pages linked to from the library reference *do* list all the methods of the classes and it's fairly complete. However, if you want a javadoc style browser, consider using [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html). It should come with your standard Python install. Typing `pydoc -p 8080` will open a server on port 8080 that you can browse and look at. There seems to be a hosted version on http://pydoc.org/ too.

Comment: [This](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) (linked to from the library reference manual) covers the built in types (which is what, I presume, you mean by "standard" types). Personally, I just launch an interpreter and use the builtin `help` and autocomplete to figure this kind of stuff out. Much quicker.

Comment: Of course, this is what I linked to as well, just wanted to point out that the index is not particularly helpful for the specific problem where an overview of `dict`s methods is needed.

Comment: For an overview, I think you're right. Have you tried using the interpreter directly? Most Python programmers tend to do that since it's a lot quicker and easier. Just start up the interpreter and type `dict.` and hit the tab key twice (assuming readline is enabled). Otherwise, a `dir(dict)` will give you all the methods as a list and you can say `help(dict.update)` to get the help for the method directly.

Comment: As I said, I don't have a problem getting documentation, I'm not the author of the question ;)

Comment: Heck, I didn't notice that. :)